# Where is stored recovery key for encrypted partition recovery key

Tags: partitioning, backup, encryption, lvm

during setup of 21.10 I chose to use LVM Encrypted file system.
I set recovery password and setup show where will be stored on the
disk. The path look quite simple. Now I want to backup stored data
but cannot find this directory. Please point me default location
of recovery data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was lost. As @Halil Sen explained it was written on volatile location and not available after restart. So the solution is to use this mathodology to generate new recovery key [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1334372/119863)

Answer (score 2):

If you have used an Ubuntu Live USB for the install and if you hadn't changed the default location, the recovery.key is gone I am afraid. The default location points to the `/home` of the live USB which is not persistent -- i.e., gets cleaned after poweroff.

[image]

Comment: Is there a chance to regenerate this recovery key now when I have full access to the system ?

Comment: @AdamMierzwiak I strongly suspect that you cannot get the key as a plain text since the comparison is done after hashing, albeit there is nothing special about the default recovery.key file (and the password itself) automatically generated by ubuntu -- except that the password is made of 48 random digits and the recovery.key file is a plain-text file that only contains this 48-digit password. 

With that said, you can remove the lost key and generate/add a new recovery key yourself and save it in a text file following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1334372/119863)

Comment: So to get the key during installation process do we need additional usb memory (e.g. pendrive)? When I try to save it on mounted installation medium I see that most locations are read-only

Comment: @AdamMierzwiak you need to make your Ubuntu installation disk "persistent" (i.e., it needs to retain the information after the installation). Here is a link https://www.howtogeek.com/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/ (I skimmed over it but didn't try this myself, if you google "persistent ubuntu installation usb" you can find more sources).