# External drives don't mount when using the 21.10 installer >> Cannot save recovery key to safe storage location

Tags: encryption, 21.10

Maybe I am being dense, but I cannot figure out how to save the recovery key to an external drive.

[As already answered here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372174/where-is-stored-recovery-key-for-encrypted-partition-recovery-key), saving the key in the default location isn't that useful, as it is not a persistent location.

But I also cannot find a way to mount any external volume while processing the installation:

- any USB drive I plug in does not appear to mount, as I don't see them in the file manager when I try to choose a different destination
- I cannot see any obvious way of opening any other tool (i.e. "Disks" or "Terminal"), so I have no way to figure out if the external drive just needs to be mounted manually

### Steps to reproduce

1. Prepare a 21.10 USB boot drive
2. Boot from the USB drive, and choose `Install Ubuntu`
3. Opt to wipe the whole drive, then in the advanced settings, choose to encrypt
4. When asked, generate a recovery key
5. Connect another USB drive, the one that you want to use as a destination for your recovery key
6. Click on the button near the path field to choose a different destination.

Thanks!

Comment: You already know the answer to the question you are asking here...  You even linked to it!  It sounds like your actual problem is with mounting volumes, so why didn't you ask about that and provide details about that problem? As you've asked this question, it's a duplicate.  If you need help with your actual problem and cannot find a good solution after searching, then you should start a new question providing details about your actual problem.

Comment: All detected volumes will show in "Disks"-- mounted or not. If they don't automatically mount, select the volume and click the "play" arrow to mount.  It's not clear why you can't open a terminal. You should provide more details about this in another question if you need to ask how to open your terminal

Comment: I edited the post to make the problem a bit clearer. In short, it doesn't look like I can open any other tool while using the installer, so I cannot check `Disks` nor use `Terminal` to figure out what is happening to the drives I plug in.

Comment: Then you should open a live session (Try Ubuntu), mount whatever drives you need and then run the installer.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. At least I am not missing anything obvious. How do I flag this as an issue though? This is a UX problem the devs might want to address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is stored recovery key for encrypted partition recovery key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372174/where-is-stored-recovery-key-for-encrypted-partition-recovery-key)

Comment: No, Lorenz, but thanks for trying.
 I already linked to that question in my original post. The problem I am highlighting here is of a UX nature. There doesn't seem to be an intuitive way to save the key to another volume. At this point, I'd be curious to know what's the best way to flag this behavior as a potential bug to the developers.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the SSH server during the installation and connected from my client PC. I just copied the key.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1228401)

Comment: This is not really a viable solution for the average user using the "installation wizard".