# How to generate a new recovery key for an encrypted ZFS NVMe SSD boot drive?

Tags: encryption, 22.04, zfs, nvme

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 via an installation USB on an encrypted ZFS NVMe SSD. Woot. Things are sweet.

Only, since this is my first time through, I did not savvy the need to copy the recovery key from /home/ubuntu while the installation USB was still in session. Woops!

Not to worry! I totally have my new passcode and access to the new system.

**How can I dispense with the old recovery key, and generate a new recovery key?**

Treat me as needing newbish handholding (e.g., if you say something like "You just need to `foo bar /dev/nvmeXY` and then `baz -luhrman /dev/nvmeXX` and you are set" assume that I will need `/dev/nvmeXY` and `nvmeXX` spelled out at a third grade level. :)

Answers telling me to just start over with a new install are out of bounds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete/modify the recovery key from the Ubuntu 21.04 encrypted disk install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333605/how-to-delete-modify-the-recovery-key-from-the-ubuntu-21-04-encrypted-disk-insta)

Comment: @freezed Thank you! It does not appear to work with NVMe (trying that answer unsuccessfully was what led me to ask this question).

Comment: @freezed The answer you linked is for a zfs filesystem layered inside a luks encrypted partition. The new installer in ubuntu 22.04 installs zfs with native encryption so the direction there do not fit.